# Cartesian plot to polar plot conversion

Tags: python, polar-coordinates

I've got linear plot like this:
[linear plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hzsu.png)

and I want to create polar plot using:

```
def cart2pol(x, y):
    rho = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
    phi = np.arctan2(y, x)
    return(rho, phi)
```

but I do not unstarstand how it works. How can I create a plot in polar coordinates using above def?

To create linear plot I'm using

```
ax.plot(xd, yd2)
```

where: xd=range(0,50) and yd2 = yd[0:50], yd - data from my signal.

next:

```
xd_2 = xd[2:50]
yd3 = yd[2:50]
def cart2pol(xd_2, yd3):
    xdkw = np.power(xd_2,2)
    yd3kw = np.power(yd3,2)
    rho = np.sqrt(xdkw + yd3kw)
    phi = np.arctan2(yd3kw, xdkw)
    return(rho, phi)
```

and next:

```
plt.polar(cart2pol(xd_2,yd3))
```

and I get an error:

```
ValueError: x and y can be no greater than 2-D, but have shapes (2,) and (2, 50, 48)
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to plot using `phi` as the horizontal axis and `rho` as the vertical axis?

Comment: As "r" and "theta" in polar coordinates

Comment: [Matplotlib.pyplot.polar](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.polar.html)

Comment: okej, but how can I convert my linear plot into polar?
In matlab is a cmd: cart2pol, and it's all.

Comment: The `x` and `y`- lists (or numpy arrays) that you used to plot initially can be converted to polar coordinates using `cart2pol(x,y)` you defined and then plot it using `matplotlib.pyplot.polar`. I'm not sure where exactly the problem is here.

Comment: After 
```
def cart2pol(xd, yd2):
    rho = np.sqrt(xd**2 + yd2**2)
    phi = np.arctan2(yd2, xd)
    return(rho, phi)

plt.polar(rho, phi)
   ```
I get an error: NameError: name 'rho' is not defined

Comment: Again, without context of where the error occurs, there is no way of knowing the problem. Also, the question needs to be updated accordingly. Right now, it doesn't mean anything.

Comment: I updated the question. Now maybe the situation is clear.

Comment: I'm not sure why the shape is so out. One thing I noticed was the sequence of plotting. The function `cart2pol` returns `rho` and `phi` in this order, and `polar` uses `theta` and `r` in this exact order. Try using it that way.

Comment: I give up,what I have to write in my code? 
`
def cart2pol(yd3,xd_2):
    xdkw = np.power(xd_2,2)
    yd3kw = np.power(yd3,2)
    rho = np.sqrt(xdkw + yd3kw)
    phi = np.arctan2(yd3kw, xdkw)
    return(rho, phi)

plt.figure()
plt.polar(cart2pol(yd3,xd_2)) 
`
this give me an error: ValueError: x and y can be no greater than 2-D, but have shapes (2,) and (2, 48, 1)

Answer (score 0):

This method converts the Cartesian coordinate (x, y) into the equivalent polar coordinate (rho, phi) and returns it.

In the 2-D polar coordinate system, a point is represented by (ρ, φ),
where

- ρ (rho) - Radial Coordinate, which is the distance of the point from the origin
- φ (phi) - Angular Coordinate, which is the angle that the line joining the origin and the point makes with the reference direction.

Converting a cartesian system to polar system

- The x-axis is taken as the reference direction in the corresponding polar plane
- For a coordinate (X, Y), ρ = sqrt(X^2+Y^2)
- For a coordinate (X, Y), φ = atan2(Y, X). Note - To understand why we use atan2 instead of atan, check this answer [Python atan or atan2, what should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35749246/python-atan-or-atan2-what-should-i-use)

The polar coordinates can be plotted in this manner:

```
cartesian_coordinates = [(1, 2), (-3, 4), (5, 6)]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
for x, y in cartesian_coordinates:
    rho, phi = cart2pol(x, y)
    ax.plot(phi, rho)
```

Comment: But, after using above code I get plot like this: https://imgur.com/bj498O5 and it's not properly

I use:
`cartesian_coordinates = [(x,y)]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
for x, y in cartesian_coordinates:
    rho, phi = cart2pol(x, y)
    ax.plot(phi, rho)`
where x,y is a coordinate which create my linear plot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hzsu.png)