# Phase calculated by np.angle python different from value obtained by calculating arctan of imaginary part divided by real part of the complex number

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, fft, complex-numbers

I'm trying to find phase of a particular point in the FFT of a signal in python. The complex number obtained at that point is

```
complex_num = -64.97135784885555 + 30.016069249920577j
```

Using the python function `numpy.angle` the answer is **2.7088133115162574 radians** and in degrees it's **155.20357023873785**. But when I calculate `numpy.arctan(img/real)`, I'm getting the result **-0.43277934207353586**. Why am I getting two different values? Can anyone please explain what am I doing wrong here?

Further looking into it I found both of these values could be equivalent representations of the same angle. But I didn't understand how is it so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python atan or atan2, what should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35749246/python-atan-or-atan2-what-should-i-use)

Comment: Knowing `angle` uses `atan2`, the linked question asks the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Just to explain it a little bit more:

```
import numpy as np
complex_num = -64.97135784885555 + 30.016069249920577j
np.angle(complex_num)
#2.7088133115162574       #radian
np.angle(complex_num,deg=True)
#155.20357023873785       #degrees
```

---

```
np.arctan(30.016069249920577/-64.97135784885555)
#-0.43277934207353586    #radian
```

Convert radian to degree by: `np.rad2deg()`

```
np.rad2deg(-0.43277934207353586)
#-24.796429761262143     #degrees
```

Now, if you want to represent this is first coordinate add `180`

```
-24.796429761262143 +180
#155.20357023873785
```

This is exactly similar to `np.angle(complex_num,deg=True)`

Hope this clarifies.

Links:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.angle.html

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arctan.html

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in you assumption. Both values represent the same angle, just from a different "perspective".

`numpy.angle` returns values [in the range [-pi, pi]](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.angle.html), while `numpy.arctan` returns values [in the range [-pi/2, pi/2]](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arctan.html), which is why the returned values differ.

Comment: They are not the same angle, they differ by 180 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

For such a calculation, instead of `numpy.arctan(y/x)`, you should use `numpy.arctan2(y, x)`:

```
In [22]: complex_num = -64.97135784885555 + 30.016069249920577j

In [23]: np.arctan2(complex_num.imag, complex_num.real)
Out[23]: 2.7088133115162574
```

Since `arctan2` keeps the real and imaginary parts as separate arguments, it can distinguish between the second and fourth quadrants of the complex plane.